# Push em JSON Object AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, array, ionic

Como faço para adicionar 1 item em um objeto json no angularJS.
No caso tenho: `{COD: 29, MOTIVO: "teste"}`
E gostaria que ficasse: `{COD: 29, MOTIVO: "teste", ID : 12345789}`

Tentei da seguinte forma:

```
$scope.cadastroSolicitacao = function(values){
    $scope.v = values;
    $scope.v.push({MATRICULA : '123456789'})
    //console.log($scope.v);
};
```

No caso acima, quando eu clicasse no botão que contem o formulario ele executaria a funcao `cadastroSolicitacao` pegar os valores do mesmo e adicionar esse item `MATRICULA`, porem não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo simples com [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) é acessar o objeto e criar um novo item com aqueles que já existem:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.v = [{
      COD: 29,
      MOTIVO: "teste"
    }, {
      COD: 30,
      MOTIVO: "teste"
    }];
    $scope.addMatricula = function(obj, value) {
      obj.MATRICULA = value;      
      console.log($scope.v);
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div  ng-repeat="value in v">
    {{value.COD}} {{value.MOTIVO}} {{ value.MATRICULA }}
    <input ng-model="MAT" /> 
    <button type="button" ng-click="addMatricula(value,MAT)">Adiconar Matricula</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

O método `.push()` serve apenas para inserir um novo item em um `Array`.

Para inserir um atributo novo em um objeto você pode fazer assim:

```
$scope.v.MATRICULA = '123456789'
```

ou

```
$scope.v['MATRICULA'] = '123456789'
```

Não existe uma maneira de fazer isso no `angular`, isso é `javascript`.

Comment: "*Não existe uma maneira de fazer isso no angular, isso é javascript*". Que? Angular é JavaScript.

Comment: @jbueno justamente o que eu quis explicar. Pra responder a primeira linha da pergunta: "Como faço para adicionar 1 item em um objeto json no angularJS."